# Loaded 12.10 wireless connects but does not load internet

Tags: 12.10

Loaded 12.10 wireless connects but does not load internet, but it does load after restarting the computer. It is just frustrating to have start the computer twice to go online. I'm using a Lenovo think pad.

Comment: Are you using a router? Have you tried to connect to it, after first booting your pc?

Comment: Yes that is not it.

Comment: Have same problem... only after upgrade from 12.04... worked like a charm before,  and other computers connect without a hassle..  route -n    shows the wlan router and not more.  Similarly,  ifconfig  shows  wlan0  and that "looks" about okay... aarrrgh

Answer (score 0):

This guy up here is crazy. lol
What kind of wireless card are you using? A lot of times the Ubuntu built-in kernel driver is jacked up. So, you end up having to install a different driver and blacklist the default one. If you give me the device name I'll try to pinpoint a driver for you.